# Is there any reason to disable VR in Nikon lenses?

Tags: nikon, image-stabilization

Is there any reason to disable VR in Nikon lenses? Perhaps it is safer to storage/carry lenses with VR disabled? Or, maybe with very small shorted speed VR decrease quality of picture?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For storage you don't have to disable VR, but you should wait for the VR system to be disengaged (take your finger off the shutter release and wait a few seconds) before turning off the camera and removing the lens.  This isn't critical, but if you wait, the VR elements will lock in place and not rattle around as the lens is moved.  See article here: [Removing a VR lens from a camera](https://nikoneurope-en.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/21602/kw/VR).

Thom Hogan[2](http://www.bythom.com/nikon-vr.htm) says it better than I could - basically you ought to leave VR off until you have a situation where it is needed: for example, at high shutter speeds (1/500th and faster) VR may decrease IQ as the vibration reduction frequency may be slower than the shutter speed and be out of sync, and for many VR lenses, you should switch off VR if you are using a tripod.   So better to switch it on when needed, rather than leaving it on all the time - good advice I think.

Comment: thanks that was helpful. Do you know whether d5100 auto detecting tripod/timer?

Answer (score 0):

To save on battery usage. 
When my battery is getting low I turn off VR first. Then when the battery gets lower, I turn off auto focus. If my battery is real low and I need to take a couple more pictures, then I'll also turn off the post-view on the back of the camera (full film camera mode X_X )

On my Nikon D2hs the shutter is so fast, I seldom need VR. My Fuji S3 has a slow, lazy, shutter-mirror action, so I can benefit from VR almost 100% of the time. My Nikon D1x has seen better days. It has a strong kick, like a shotgun. It needs VR on medium and slower speeds.